# Custom view attribute wrap_content not work

Tags: android, android-custom-view

A bit difficult to explain, hope everyone get my point.

At onMeasure() I done this to make wrap_content work as expect.

```
 // Measure Width
        if (widthMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
            //Must be this size
            width = widthSize;
        } else if (widthMode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST) {
            //Can't be bigger than...
            width = Math.min(desiredWidth, widthSize);
        } else {
            //Be whatever you want
            width = desiredWidth;
        }
```

but `deiredWidth` required `getHeight()` method to calculate

which getHight() not ready so, I can't calculate correct value from here.

So, is there a way to get given width from layout_width attribute at onMeasure()

or do I misunderstand somethings.

**All Relevant Code**

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

    int width;
    int height;

    int widthSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    int widthMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec);
    int heightSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
    int heightMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);

    int desiredWidth = getTotalIndicatorWidth(getMeasuredHeight());
    int desiredHeight = DEFAULT_HEIGHT;

    // Measure Width
    if (widthMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
        //Must be this size
        width = widthSize;
    } else if (widthMode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST) {
        //Can't be bigger than...
        width = Math.min(desiredWidth, widthSize);
    } else {
        //Be whatever you want
        width = desiredWidth;
    }

    //Measure Height
    if (heightMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
        //Must be this size
        height = heightSize;
    } else if (heightMode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST) {
        //Can't be bigger than...
        height = Math.min(desiredHeight, heightSize);
    } else {
        //Be whatever you want
        height = desiredHeight;
    }

    setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
}

private int getTotalIndicatorWidth(int h) {
    int width = 0;
    int indicatorWidth = (h == 0) ? DEFAULT_HEIGHT : h;
    for (int i = 0; i < indicatorSize; i++) {
        if (i != 0) {
            width = width + indicatorSpacing + indicatorWidth;
        } else {
            width = indicatorWidth;
        }
    }
    return width;
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    pen.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    pen.setColor(indicatorColor);
    pen.setStrokeWidth(indicatorStokeWidth);
    pen.setAntiAlias(true);

    drawIndicator(canvas, indicatorSize, 1);
}

private void drawIndicator(Canvas paper, int indicatorSize, int position) {

    int indent = 0;
    int cr = (getHeight() / 2) - getPaddingTop() - getPaddingBottom() - indicatorStokeWidth;
    int cx = cr + getPaddingLeft() + indicatorStokeWidth;
    int cy = (getHeight() / 2) + getPaddingTop() - getPaddingBottom();

    for (int i = 0; i < indicatorSize; i++) {
        paper.drawCircle(cx + indent, cy, cr, pen);
        indent = (cr * 2) + (indicatorStokeWidth) + indent;
        if ((i+1) < indicatorSize) {
            indent += indicatorSpacing;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, the below image shown the area of custom view even it `layout_width` was set as `wrap_content` but it doesn't work for me now.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You say that you need to access `getHeight()` to calculate `desiredWidth` inside the `onMeasure()` method and also that `getHeight()` is not ready.

Yes, `getHeight()` or `getWidth()` can't be accessed from `onMeasure()` because these `height` and `width` are set in `onMeasure()` method. In your `onMeause()` method, you need to call `setMeasuredDimension()`. You have done that in your code.

```
 setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
```

This `width` is what you will get when you call `getWidth()` and this `height` is what you will get when you call `getHeight()`.

So if you want to access `getHeight()`, then use `height` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The following code solve my problem of how can I get my `layout_width` or `layout_height` at `onMesaure()` so I can calculate my view correctly when user request for `wrap_content`

```
public PageIndicator(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    int[] attrsArray = new int[] {
            android.R.attr.id,              // 0
            android.R.attr.background,      // 1
            android.R.attr.layout_width,    // 2
            android.R.attr.layout_height,   // 3
    };

    TypedArray taa = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, attrsArray);
    TypedArray ta = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.PageIndicator, 0, 0);

    try {
        indicatorColor = ta.getColor(R.styleable.PageIndicator_indicator_color, Color.WHITE);
        indicatorStokeWidth = (int) ta.getDimension(R.styleable.PageIndicator_indicator_stokeWidth, 4);
        indicatorSpacing = (int) ta.getDimension(R.styleable.PageIndicator_indicator_spacing, 5);
        indicatorSize = ta.getInteger(R.styleable.PageIndicator_indicator_size, 3);
        indicatorPosition = ta.getInteger(R.styleable.PageIndicator_indicator_startPosition, 0);

        mLayoutWidth = taa.getLayoutDimension(2, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        mLayoutHeight = taa.getLayoutDimension(3, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    } finally {
        ta.recycle();
        taa.recycle();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not the right way of doing it. Always use the `width` and `height` sent to the `onMeasure()` method. Based on "wrap_content" or "match_parent" or any specific size you set like "200dp" in the layout xml, you will get these in the `onMeasure()` method with differnt mode lie "AT_MOST" or "UNSPECIFIED" or "EXACTLY". Use this `mode` and `size` from the `spec`.

Comment: Yes, I define "AT_MOST" or "UNSPECIFIED" or "EXACTLY" but, if you see my code above `width = Math.min(desiredWidth, widthSize);` my `desireWidth` is the width of my custom view which each circle relative to its view height and when AT_MOST was triggered if layout_height was assigned an exactly value I need  to get these height from `getHeight()` not `heightMeasureSpec` which return height of parent and because `getHeight() `cannot get in `onMeasure()` this is one method that I can think of. If you have best practice please share an answer.